# Recurring Logentries crash notification on Heroku (NodeJS server)

Tags: node.js, heroku, logentries

I've running a NodeJS-based application server on Heroku, and this morning it started crashing repeatedly. It runs one traditional 1x dyno (i.e. the free tier). Heroku takes it down due to idleness, which is fine, but it then gets into a state where I get a crash notification from Logentries every few seconds indefinitely.

I can stop it by taking manually taking the server down to 0 dynos, and then back up to 1.

Note that the very first thing the server does is print a debugging message to console.log, so the fact that I'm not seeing that in the middle of all these crash messages suggests that my app isn't even being run.

Any idea what might be causing this?

```
02 <45>1 2015-12-05T21:03:30.039646+00:00 heroku web.1 - - Idling
125 <45>1 2015-12-05T21:03:30.040156+00:00 heroku web.1 - - State changed from up to down
131 <45>1 2015-12-05T21:03:34.298780+00:00 heroku web.1 - - Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
301 <158>1 2015-12-05T21:03:35.730386+00:00 heroku router - - at=info method=GET path="/" host=<server name redacted>.herokuapp.com request_id=e3c6cdbf-3012-4e5e-ab89-24e8c2eb0e03 fwd="50.0.151.247" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2085875ms status=101 bytes=189
310 <158>1 2015-12-05T21:03:36.299732+00:00 heroku router - - at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=<server name redacted>.herokuapp.com request_id=35c719d9-5153-49e8-a640-91f848f853b9 fwd="50.0.151.247" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
310 <158>1 2015-12-05T21:03:36.730513+00:00 heroku router - - at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=<server name redacted>.herokuapp.com request_id=138f048e-4229-4e9f-9e56-8d0d9e691734 fwd="50.0.151.247" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
126 <45>1 2015-12-05T21:03:36.690366+00:00 heroku web.1 - - Process exited with status 143
310 <158>1 2015-12-05T21:03:40.160167+00:00 heroku router - - at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=<server name redacted>.herokuapp.com request_id=0a451a1b-04f2-4f59-bc1e-abc1f2599607 fwd="50.0.151.247" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
310 <158>1 2015-12-05T21:03:40.586679+00:00 heroku router - - at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=<server name redacted>.herokuapp.com request_id=c7681cce-f486-447b-9f76-b36a8db3570b fwd="50.0.151.247" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
310 <158>1 2015-12-05T21:03:44.024709+00:00 heroku router - - at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=<server name redacted>.herokuapp.com request_id=ddd8187f-c8c7-45aa-8add-863b17bdfc5f fwd="50.0.151.247" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the version of node I was using (4.2.1) was attempting to use more than the 512MB of memory available on a traditional 1x dyno (this is why Node kept crashing before it executed even the first line of my server code). The solution was to modify the Procfile to cap Node's memory usage to fit into the available memory. The Procfile now looks like so:

```
web: node --optimize_for_size --max_old_space_size=500 --gc_interval=100 server.js
```

(note that it's 500 rather than 512 out of my habitual desire to be a wee bit conservative).